# RateLimitingError when communicating with OpenAI API

Tags: python, chatgpt-api

I am trying to get ChatGPT OpenAI API up and running with this little python script:

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a poetic assistant, skilled in explaining complex programming concepts with creative flair."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Compose a poem that explains the concept of recursion in programming."}
  ]
)

print(completion.choices[0].message)
```

The script however gives me the following error:

```
RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. 'type': 'insufficient_quota', 'param': None, 'code':'insufficient_quota'}}
```

My quota however is $5, which is more than enough for this simple prompt. Is this a code problem, or a should I simply add credits to my OpenAI account?

Comment: Did you check your token history e.g. how many requests you sent with the token and how much it consumed?

Comment: Yes, the amount of requests that has gone trough is zero. I just set up a new account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoding to [Rate limits](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/rate-limits), there are 5 types of rate limits:

- RPM (requests per minute)
- RPD (requests per day)
- TPM (tokens per minute)
- TPD (tokens per day)
- IPM (images per minute)

In your case, you may hit `RPM` or `RPD`. You can check [Rate limits in headers](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/rate-limits-in-headers) or your [account page](https://platform.openai.com/account/rate-limits) to confirm this.

You can use this Python code ([src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77605691/how-to-get-headers-from-openai-api/77691790#77691790)):

```py
raw_response = client.chat.completions.with_raw_response.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a poetic assistant, skilled in explaining complex programming concepts with creative flair."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Compose a poem that explains the concept of recursion in programming."}
  ]
)

chat_completion = raw_response.parse()
response_headers = raw_response.headers
print(response_headers)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ultimately the issue was resolved after linking my credit card and adding 10 USD to the account